# Material UI - How do you make a horizontal List?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In Material UI, I'd like to use:

`List` and `ListItem` but have them appear horizontally.

What's the best way?

Comment: Use the Display Inline from [Display MUI](https://mui.com/system/display/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In **MUI v5**, you can use [`Stack`](https://mui.com/components/stack/#direction) to display a list of thingies in vertical or horizontal direction. It uses flexbox under the hood so the `direction` prop is mapped to the good old `flex-direction` in CSS:

```
<Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
  <Item>Item 1</Item>
  <Item>Item 2</Item>
  <Item>Item 3</Item>
</Stack>
```

Or if you're using a `List`:

```
<List component={Stack} direction="row">
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Then what if you chose to use List to have the ability to specify the selected Item?

Comment: Not an accessible solution, since Stack contains div at its root, and divs shouldn't wrap li elements. Instead, ul should be used. An accessibility test would fail on this part.

Answer (score 60):

So far I have:

```
const flexContainer = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  padding: 0,
};

return (
  <List style={flexContainer}>
    <ListItem
      primaryText="foo1"
      secondaryText="bar1"/>
    <ListItem
      primaryText="foo2"
      secondaryText="bar2"/>
  </List>
);
```

This works.  Looking for a potential better answer / opinions.  Should this be built in?

Comment: This works nicely. I'm still amazed that they don't have a built in attribute to achieve this.

Comment: Having gotten back into this stuff, after a hiatus, The `Stack` and `direction` solutions provided below by @NearHuscarl are almost definitely what you're looking for.  I will try to mark it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 4):

None of these worked for me, so i bring the 2021 version i guess:

```
        <List style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', padding: 0 }}>
            <ListItem button>hehe</ListItem>
            <ListItem button>hehe1</ListItem>
        </List>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really seeing the difference?

Comment: The only difference is really the on attributes, that are outdated in the solutions below

Answer (score 2):

After playing around

```
.list-horizontal-display > div {
    display: inline-block;
}

<List className="list-horizontal-display" >
   <ListItem leftAvatar={<Avatar icon={this.props.icon}/>}></ListItem>
   <ListItem leftAvatar={<Avatar icon={this.props.icon}/>}><ListItem>
</List
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your approach will work. My question is when you want to view this on mobile. The flex direction needs to change to a column.

Will be better if used `display: inline-block`  but the ListItem component will add a div wrapper for each item.

Will be better if ListItem is actually using the containerElement as a top level wrapper instead of the div element.

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't answer the question (since you've asked to use the `<List>` and `<ListItem>` components), the [Material UI Gridlist](https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/#single-line-grid-list) might be of interest to some people, if they wanted something more visual.